# RF switch(1:14 or 1:16) without signal distortion

Tags: rf, switches

I am looking for an RF switch with no signal distortion in the 1 to 2 GHz band.
I need a 1:14 or 1:16 switch, could you recommend switches(for example, an optical switch or a semiconductor switch etc)??

And I wonder if the RF switch has a lot of signal distortion. Does it change much in the case of amplitude or phase?

Comment: Product recommendation questions are unfortunately off-topic on this site. A discussion about a specific RF switch or the theory behind it etc would be fine though.

Comment: Also, the only switches with no signal distortion are made from unicorn hair.

Answer (score 1):

All switches have distortion, but some less than others.

MEMs technology uses metal to metal contacts, a micromachined relay in fact, so you'd expect it to have very little distortion. They are still quite poor on hot switching, due to the very small geometries. That's the main reason I couldn't use them.

Silicon on sapphire CMOS technology is very good, IIP3s in the 50 to 80dBm in your frequency range. Have a look at [Peregrine](https://www.psemi.com/products/rf-switches) (no affiliation, but used them a lot) to see what sort of performance is available. There are other suppliers.

PIN diodes are still a strong player for RF switching, though not as convenient as the above two newer types, as you need to apply bias through the RF lines. As they are diodes, you can do clever logic through a string of them, pulling current from different nodes, to implement a high fanout multiplexer, which reduces the number of bias chokes needed. These are often used in switchable lowpass filters, pull current from the filter and it passes through the filter's inductors into the input and output multiplexer strings, short string for high frequency, long string for low frequency to help balance the RF loss through the system.

Comment: Can you name any actual mems switch makers? When I look it seems to be papers and promises.

Comment: @HenryCrun It's been like nuclear fusion, MEMs RF switches being just a few years away for the last couple of decades, very disappointing. I left the industry 4 years ago and then Analog Devices had bought somebody and were making a MEMs switch offering, with marginally less appalling hotswitch capability than others. But they don't seem to be on their website now, I didn't check before posting. I guess SOI has made such ground over the last decade, that MEMs have gone back off the boil, a technology with a bright future behind it.